# Queston on the definition of singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

From the Hatcher's 
[image]

can someone told me why $\sigma$ has singularities ?

Thank you

Comment: Cusps, self-intersections, such stuff _is allowed_. $\sigma$ may be quite pathological, for example a space-filling curve (if $n = 1$). It can also be nice.

Comment: @DanielFischer i dont understand you ?

Comment: A singular simplex $\sigma$ can be quite nice, an embedding, if $X$ is a differentiable manifold, it can be smooth. But it can also be quite un-nice. A singular $1$-simplex for example could be a Peano curve, it may have self-intersections, or any other kind of bad behaviour, as long as it is just continuous. For a singular $n$-simplex in an $\mathbb{R}^m$, the image set can have topological dimension $\neq n$, in some places it can have higher dimension, in others lower, it can be _wild_.

Answer (score 2):

The author is emphasising the difference between a singular simplex and a simplicial simplex. Among other things, a simplicial simplex has to be an injective map when restricted to its interior. This simply isn't the case for singular simplexes - they can be as non-injective (or singular) as they like - we only require that they are continuous maps.

It's helpful to give an example of how this affects computations. Given that the singular chain complex of a space is almost always incalculable, I'll use a single point as the example space.

When calculating the simplicial complex associated to $\{\ast\}$ we note that there exists exactly one simplicial simplex $\sigma_0\colon\Delta_0\to\{\ast\}$ and there exist no higher simplicial simplexes because any such simplex would fail to be injective on their interior. It follows that the associated chain complex is given by $$\cdots\to 0\to 0\to \mathbb{Z}_{ \langle \sigma_0 \rangle}.$$

Now, what about the associated singular chain complex for $\{\ast\}$? Well, there is still exactly one simplex $\sigma_0\colon\Delta_0\to\{\ast\}$ but now we also have exactly one continuous map (and so singular simplex) $\sigma_n\colon\Delta_n\to\{\ast\}$ for each $n\geq 1$. It follows that the associated singular chain complex for $\{\ast\}$ is given by $$\cdots\to \mathbb{Z}_{ \langle \sigma_2 \rangle}\to \mathbb{Z}_{ \langle \sigma_1 \rangle}\to \mathbb{Z}_{ \langle \sigma_0 \rangle}.$$